# Entropy of a gas leaking out of a tank

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

There is some super-heated $NH_3$ in an isolated tank with initial pressure and temperature of $1600 \ kPa$ and $50^{\circ} C$ respectively. Gas leaks out from a valve on tank very slowly such that some of gas exits reversibly. In the final state, pressure is $1400 \ kPa$ and $NH_3$ is still super-heated.

The problem says that using mass and entropy balance show that $s_1=s_2$, where $s$ is the molar entropy of gas in tank.

Using the total entropy balance for inside of tank as control volume, we get

$$(m_2 s_2 -m_1 s_1)_{C.V.}=-\dot{m_e} s_e \Delta t$$

What is $s_e$ now? It's not constant! How can I reduce this equation to $s_2=s_1$.

Comment: As @Rishabh Jain points out, the equation should read $$\left(\frac{d(ms)}{dt}\right)_{C.V.}=-\dot{m}_es$$where $$\dot{m}_e=-\frac{dm}{dt}$$

Comment: @Chester Miller : For the first equation, why is the right side specific entropy the same as that on left side?

Comment: That is the current value of the specific entropy in the tank (value leaving the tank, assuming tank is well-mixed).

Comment: Thanks for the information :) Sir, take a look at my new question?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/373318/can-we-use-a-equation-of-state-for-a-phase-change

Comment: @ChesterMiller : Thanks. Now why, in the problem, it said "Gas leaks out from a valve on tank very slowly such that some of gas exits reversibly"? Seems that this wouldn't change the first equation.

Comment: Well, it think this choice of wording is unfortunate (and incorrect).  The entropy of the gas certainly changes in passing through the valve, and this part is certainly not reversible.  But the gas remaining within the tank has been expanding  gradually and reversibly as it pushes the gas ahead of it into the exit valve.  So, whatever gas remains in the tank has experienced an adiabatic reversible (isentropic) expansion.  So the s in the first equation is the entropy of the gas that is just entering the valve (and just leaving the tank).  The control volume includes the tank but not the valve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entropy is an extensive quantity that depends on mass. As some mass has been lost, entropy has been decreased but the molar entropy still remains the same.